# Different values reported for ALL_OBJECTS.OBJECT_ID and ALL_ARGUMENTS.OBJECT_ID in Oracle 21c

Tags: sql, oracle

I've noticed that for some objects in the `SYS` schema, the two following columns report different values:

- [`ALL_OBJECTS.OBJECT_ID`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/ALL_OBJECTS.html#GUID-AA6DEF8B-F04F-482A-8440-DBCB18F6C976)
- [`ALL_PROCEDURES.OBJECT_ID`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/ALL_PROCEDURES.html)
- [`ALL_ARGUMENTS.OBJECT_ID`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/ALL_ARGUMENTS.html#GUID-1F535054-CABC-4321-AA2F-151DA726A2D7)

For example:

```sql
select object_id
from all_objects
where object_name = 'DBMS_STATS'
and owner = 'SYS';

select distinct object_id
from all_procedures
where object_name = 'DBMS_STATS'
and owner = 'SYS';

select distinct object_id
from all_arguments
where package_name = 'DBMS_STATS'
and owner = 'SYS';
```

Produces

```
OBJECT_ID
---------
14813

OBJECT_ID
---------
14812

OBJECT_ID
---------
14812
```

[This dbfiddle reproduces it](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=9479ae406ce16680d1eb735a062baeb3):

- On Oracle 21c
- On Oracle 18c
- But not on Oracle 11g

It seems that the data contained in `ALL_OBJECTS` is wrong? I can't find any entries in `ALL_PROCEDURES` for `OBJECT_ID = 14813`, and conversely, `OBJECT_ID = 14812` produces this object in `ALL_OBJECTS`:

```sql
select owner, object_name, object_type
from all_objects
where object_id = 14812;
```

Results:

```
|OWNER |OBJECT_NAME       |OBJECT_TYPE|
|------|------------------|-----------|
|PUBLIC|XS$ROLE_GRANT_LIST|SYNONYM    |
```

Quite unrelated. Is this a known bug in the dictionary views? Or am I misunderstanding the semantics of the `OBJECT_ID`, which I believed was a unique object identifier across the dictionary?

I'm using Oracle Database 21c Express Edition Release 21.0.0.0.0 - Production from here: https://hub.docker.com/r/gvenzl/oracle-xe, though a customer of ours can also reproduce it in 19c Enterprise Edition 19.5.0.0.0

Comment: fwiw: I cannot reproduce that behavior in my non-XE 19c installation.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger: That's why I added the edition. Might be a bug in that particular build by gvenzl, when he removes some objects to make the docker image even smaller. That might explain why it can be reproduced on dbfiddle, as it probably also uses that image.

Comment: It looks like the views have been substantially rewritten. In 11g they all refer to the same underlying table to get `obj#`; in 21c only `all_objects` uses that, directly anyway; the others use `int$dba_procedures` and `int$dba_arguments`. Still seems like they should be aligned, of course, but wonder if something is wrong within those. Can't see them on db<>fiddle though.

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger: A customer of ours is using 19.c (19.15.0.0.0) with the same bug, so it doesn't seem to be XE related.

Comment: Yeah, I now found a 19.15.0.0.0 non-XE installation where I have a similar (although not exactly the same) phenonomen.

Comment: @AlexPoole: The interesting thing on my DB is that I have three different object IDs when querying `all_procedures` but donly 2 different object IDS when querying the underling `int$dba_procedures` views, i.e. `all_procedures` "somehow" adds "phantom" records. In fact, the phantom ID is not even present in `sys.obj$`.

Comment: Just adding what I shared on twitter earlier- dba_procedures contains rows for both the CDB and PDB (because dbms_stats code is found in the container, not PDB), you can see which row you have with the `origin_con_id` column. In PDBs that are created fresh (eg xepdb1 and create pluggable database), there are no rows in procedureInfo$ table for some packages which come from the root container (they’re not compiled in the PDB). This table is used in the dba_procedures view, because the table is empty for the PDB (for dbms_stats) only the root row appears in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try it with and without the database being a pluggable database, eg

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> select object_id, object_type
  2  from all_objects
  3  where object_name = 'DBMS_STATS'
  4  and owner = 'SYS';

 OBJECT_ID OBJECT_TYPE
---------- -----------------------
     13795 PACKAGE
     19194 PACKAGE BODY

SQL>
SQL> select distinct object_id
  2  from all_procedures
  3  where object_name = 'DBMS_STATS'
  4  and owner = 'SYS';

 OBJECT_ID
----------
     13795

SQL> alter session set container = pdb1;

Session altered.

SQL> select object_id, object_type
  2  from all_objects
  3  where object_name = 'DBMS_STATS'
  4  and owner = 'SYS';

 OBJECT_ID OBJECT_TYPE
---------- -----------------------
     13796 PACKAGE
     19191 PACKAGE BODY

SQL>
SQL> select distinct object_id
  2  from all_procedures
  3  where object_name = 'DBMS_STATS'
  4  and owner = 'SYS';

 OBJECT_ID
----------
     13795
    127365
```

My hypothesis is that the ALL_ARGUMENTS et al are referring back to the "true" owning object, namely the one in the root container.

Plenty of weird little pointers and stuff going on here to support multi-tenant, eg

```
SQL> conn / as sysdba
Connected.
SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW','DBA_ARGUMENTS') from dual;

DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL('VIEW','DBA_ARGUMENTS')
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---

  CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE NONEDITIONABLE VIEW "SYS"."DBA_ARGUMENTS" ("OWNER", "OBJECT_NAME", "PA
LOA
D", "SUBPROGRAM_ID", "ARGUMENT_NAME", "POSITION", "SEQUENCE", "DATA_LEVEL", "DATA_TYPE", "DEFAUL
_LE
NGTH", "IN_OUT", "DATA_LENGTH", "DATA_PRECISION", "DATA_SCALE", "RADIX", "CHARACTER_SET_NAME", "
_SU
BNAME", "TYPE_LINK", "TYPE_OBJECT_TYPE", "PLS_TYPE", "CHAR_LENGTH", "CHAR_USED", "ORIGIN_CON_ID"
  select
   OWNER, OBJECT_NAME, PACKAGE_NAME, OBJECT_ID, OVERLOAD,
   SUBPROGRAM_ID, ARGUMENT_NAME, POSITION, SEQUENCE,
   DATA_LEVEL, DATA_TYPE, DEFAULTED, DEFAULT_VALUE, DEFAULT_LENGTH,
   IN_OUT, DATA_LENGTH, DATA_PRECISION, DATA_SCALE, RADIX,
   CHARACTER_SET_NAME, TYPE_OWNER, TYPE_NAME, TYPE_SUBNAME,
   TYPE_LINK, TYPE_OBJECT_TYPE, PLS_TYPE, CHAR_LENGTH, CHAR_USED, ORIGIN_CON_ID
from INT$DBA_ARGUMENTS


SQL> alter session set container = pdb1;

Session altered.

SQL> select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('VIEW','DBA_ARGUMENTS') from dual;
ERROR:
ORA-31603: object "DBA_ARGUMENTS" of type VIEW not found in schema "SYS"
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 6731
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_SYS_ERROR", line 105
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 6718
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_METADATA", line 9734
ORA-06512: at line 1

SQL> select count(*)
  2  from dba_objects
  3  where object_name = 'DBA_ARGUMENTS'
  4  and object_type = 'VIEW';

  COUNT(*)
----------
         1
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have found here appears to be a bug in the data dictionary and was reported as Bug 34293726 - Wrong object_id in ALL_OJBECTS leading to wrong results.
Please don't get misled by the title of the bug itself, it is still to be determined whether or not the `object_id` in `all_objects` is wrong or in the other views.

The `object_id` reported in `all_objects` within the PDB is from a sub-object that is inherited by the CDB, while the other views report the `object_id` from the CDB itself.

In my database, the `DBMS_STATS` package has the `object_id` of `16334` in the CDB itself:

```sql
SQL> select object_id
from all_objects
where object_name = 'DBMS_STATS'
and owner = 'SYS';

 OBJECT_ID
----------
     16334
     22401

SQL> select distinct object_id
from all_procedures
where object_name = 'DBMS_STATS'
and owner = 'SYS';

 OBJECT_ID
----------
     16334

SQL> select distinct object_id
from all_arguments
where package_name = 'DBMS_STATS'
and owner = 'SYS';  2    3    4

 OBJECT_ID
----------
     16334
```

In the PDB, however, the object_id in all_objects is `16335`:

```sql
SQL> alter session set container=cdb1_pdb1;

Session altered.

SQL> select object_id
from all_objects
where object_name = 'DBMS_STATS'
and owner = 'SYS';

 OBJECT_ID
----------
     16335
     22398

SQL> select distinct object_id
from all_procedures
where object_name = 'DBMS_STATS'
and owner = 'SYS';

 OBJECT_ID
----------
     16334

SQL> select distinct object_id
from all_arguments
where package_name = 'DBMS_STATS'
and owner = 'SYS';

 OBJECT_ID
----------
     16334
```

What's happening here becomes clearer when looking at `cdb_objects` in the CDB (which reports all objects within a CDB, or all objects within the PDB alone when executed in the PDB itself).

```sql
SQL> select con_id, owner, object_id, object_name, object_type
 from cdb_objects
 where object_name = 'DBMS_STATS';

CON_ID OWNER  OBJECT_ID OBJECT_NAME  OBJECT_TYPE
------ ------ --------- ------------ ---------------
     1 SYS        16334 DBMS_STATS   PACKAGE
     1 SYS        22401 DBMS_STATS   PACKAGE BODY
     1 PUBLIC     16335 DBMS_STATS   SYNONYM
     3 SYS        16335 DBMS_STATS   PACKAGE
     3 SYS        22398 DBMS_STATS   PACKAGE BODY
     3 PUBLIC     16336 DBMS_STATS   SYNONYM
```

Note how `object_id` `16335` in the PDB (con_id = 3) shows up as the package itself, while in the CDB (con_id = 1) the same `object_id` is reported as the public synonym. Meanwhile, the `object_id` `16334` refers to the actual object present in the CDB which is shared across PDBs.

The missing linkage is with the other `ALL_*` views inside the PDB, which are referring to the object in the CDB with `object_id` `16334` that happens to be an entirely different object in `all_objects` in the PDB:

```sql
SQL> select con_id,owner, object_id, object_name, object_type
 from cdb_objects
 where object_id = 16334;

CON_ID OWNER  OBJECT_ID OBJECT_NAME        OBJECT_TYPE
------ ------ --------- ------------------ -----------
     3 PUBLIC     16334 XS$ROLE_GRANT_LIST SYNONYM
```

> Is this a known bug in the dictionary views? Or am I misunderstanding the semantics of the OBJECT_ID, which I believed was a unique object identifier across the dictionary?

You do understand the semantics of `object_id` correctly, this appears to be a bug and has been reported.

It may be also worthwhile to point out to other readers of this thread that one thing that has changed with the introduction of the CDB architecture is that there are multiple hierarchical dictionaries in play now. There can be up to three dictionaries: CDB --> (Application Root) --> PDB.
The Application Root container is not mandatory, in the case above the hierarchy was simply CDB --> PDB.

In either case, the child inherits the objects present in the parent, i.e. objects in the CDB are available to all Application Root containers and objects available to the Application Root container (which includes objects from the CDB) are available to the PDB.
And this is exactly what you see above in the inconsistency. Object `16334` is the object in the CDB, the actual `DBMS_STATS` package and object `16335` is the inherited package linkage in the PDB back to the CDB.

Answer (score 1):

ALL_OBJECT has the OBJECT_ID from the pluggable database.
ALL_ARGUMENTS reads the system metadata from CDB$ROOT though Extended Data Link and the OBJECT_ID comes from it:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                 | Name              | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     | Pstart| Pstop |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT          |                   |       |       |     1 (100)|          |       |       |
|*  1 |  FILTER                   |                   |       |       |            |          |       |       |
|   2 |   PARTITION LIST ALL      |                   |   200 | 44800 |     1 (100)| 00:00:01 |     1 |     2 |
|*  3 |    EXTENDED DATA LINK FULL| INT$DBA_ARGUMENTS |   200 | 44800 |     1 (100)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  4 |   FIXED TABLE FULL        | X$KZSPR           |     2 |    18 |     0   (0)|          |       |       |
|   5 |   NESTED LOOPS SEMI       |                   |     1 |    18 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
|*  6 |    FIXED TABLE FULL       | X$KZSRO           |     2 |    12 |     0   (0)|          |       |       |
|*  7 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN       | I_OBJAUTH1        |     1 |    12 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |       |       |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```